# Android EditText Visibility based on radioGroup selection

Tags: android, visibility

I need to hide `editText1` and show editText2 if `radioButton1` is selected and
I need to hide `editText2` and show editText1 if `radioButton2` is selected.
both buttons are in a radioGroup.
I am not sure if there is a radioGroup onChange event which returns which radioButton is checked?
if so, then I can do

```
EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
et1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Have you written any code to achieve this...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `OnCheckedChangeListener()` to your radioGroup:

```
      final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      final EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

      RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
      radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    if(checkedId == R.id.radioBtn1){
                       et1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       et2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
                    } else {
                       et1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                       et2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
                    }
                }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `OnCheckedChangeListener` on your `radioGroup`:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {         
        // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
        if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton1) {
            editText1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            editText2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton1) {
            editText1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editText2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: after adding this ---- private RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);---- in order to resolve the radioGroup. I still get unresolved "setOnCheckedChangeListener"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your functionality as answered by Rami and sv3k.

There is another option that you can try to achieve what you want.
That is setting onClickListener on each Radio Button.

Like this.

```
   RadioGroup  radioGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        RadioButton radio1= (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        RadioButton radio2= (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        radio1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
         {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 et1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 et2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
         });

        radio2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                et2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                et1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Post your java code, otherwise its hard to find out what problem you are facing.